# iOS Simulator hangs with beachball loader for 5-10 seconds to often

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

For almost half a year my simulator is often very slow and hangs for a couple seconds when I'm touching the running app. This happens a lot when touching TableViews or MapViews (zooming, swiping).

For example I run the app go to a mapView try to zoom in and swipe then always for 5-10 seconds the app hangs and shows the beachball (loading cursor). Then the app continues to work for a bit and it hangs again, continues to work, etc.

My colleagues don't have this problem on the same macbook (Pro late 2013, 2.3Ghz i7, 16gb, OSX 10.11.2) and same xcode project.

I've reinstalled Xcode (running latest), iOS Simulator (both iOS 8 and 9 and 9.2 have these problems).

I cannot find anything in the console and I have this with other xcode projects as well.

Hope someone can help me with this otherwise I will have to reinstall my macbook pro.

So I've tried:

- Reinstall Xcode
- Reinstall Simulators
- Looking at the console app -> all messages
- Tried other Xcode projects
- Tried other iOS version simulators
- Remove all my plugins
- Checking the CPU and Memory loads -> nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in the simulator in Xcode 7.1 and 7.2 related to accessibility.  When various accessibility introspection tools are enabled, the simulator app performs poorly.  I suggest you use the Xcode 7.3 beta or disable the tool that is triggering the issue.

See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24274

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I disabled dropbox and bettersnaptool and everything is fast again!!! From the url: Anything under "Allow these apps below to control your computer" in the Security & Privacy panel of System Preferences is a possible culprit.